# Discord.py - Trying to get number of channels, text channels & voice channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to get the number of channels, text channels & voice channels for a server info command, I've looked through the interwebs and didn't find anything

I'm not going to show the server info command fully, just where I'm trying to get the number of channels, text channels & voice channels:

```py
@client.command()
async def sinfo(ctx):
 guild=ctx.message.guild

 embed=discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.orange())

 embed.add_field(name="Server Channels: ", value=guild.channels, inline=False)
 embed.add_field(name="Server Text Channels: ", value=guild.text_channels, inline=False)
 embed.add_field(name="Server Voice Channels: ", value=guild.voice_channels, inline=False)

 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

When I say "channels" I mean both text channels & voice channels together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All 3 of those return a **list** so you just need to use `len` on them to get the number.

Do note that `guild.channels` will return both text and voice channels **including** categories.

So your solution would look like

```
total_text_channels = len(guild.text_channels)
total_voice_channels = len(guild.voice_channels)
total_channels = total_text_channels  + total_voice_channels 
embed.add_field(name="Server Channels: ", value=total_channels )
embed.add_field(name="Server Text Channels: ", value=total_text_channels )
embed.add_field(name="Server Voice Channels: ", value=total_voice_channels )
```

Add `inline=False` if you wish I removed it to make it shorter.

Also next time look up the [official API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) to save yourself from interweb.

Comment: while you're here, could you tell me how to get the amount of members in all of the guilds the bot's connected to? I want to put it in it's playing status & when it starts up

Comment: nevermind, the [official API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) told me everything