# discord.py-rewrite - Server Info Command

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a server info command but I don't know how to get the total channel count and role count. How do I get those for my embed?

*More suggestions about what kind of stuff to put for the command would be helpful :)*

Comment: Not sure about how you can get the number of roles but look at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716623/discord-py-trying-to-get-number-of-channels-text-channels-voice-channels` for no, of channels. Hope this helps

Comment: Hey there st1xkz, welcome to Stack! What have you tried to do in order to achieve your goal? Instead of simply asking the question, please provide pieces of code, which we like to call [a minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help you better, and edit your current question accordingly. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You can get channels and roles with [`discord.Guild.channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.channels) / [`discord.Guild.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.roles)

As both of this return a `list` you can use the `len()` function to get the count

```py
guild = ctx.guild or client.get_guild(123)  # or however you get the guild 

channel_count = len(guild.channel)
role_count = len(guild.roles)
```